# Android, change text size wrt orientation

Tags: java, android, xml

Good evening all. 
I've created an app using AIDE, which I'll ultimately get set up with google to sell on the play store. 
I'm presently working through the differences between portrait and landscape/horizontal. 
Presently, my app's main page doesn't allow the whole page to show when I rotate the phone to horizontal. It only shows a single line. And if I try to scroll, it doesn't allow that (not entirely a surprise, because I didn't set it up for scrolling). 
My header/intro line is set to sp=30. My subsequent lines are set to sp=20. 
I've been looking at how to deal with this issue. I.e., I want the text to resize when the orientation is changed from portrait to landscape. I have already found the androidmanifest screenOrientation="fullUser" code to allow for full rotation. This however does not deal with my real issue--- screen resizing, and text resizing, based on orientation. 
I've been reading some older posts on here discussing

get textview()

but my lack of experience in coding is now asking--- where am I suppose to place those code snippets? Would they go on mainActivity.java, and main.xml or new/different pages?

And with newer API's, is there a better/more-efficient way to do this? The articles I'm reading are 3 years old at the newest. 
TYIA.
SteveB.

Comment: In `res/layout-land`, just use a different `textSize` value

Comment: You can create different layout for potrait and landscape view, if you want to show different view

Answer (score 0):

> I want the text to resize when the orientation is changed from portrait to landscape

You're looking for how [resource quantifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) work.

You can make a `res/layout-land` or `res/values-land` folder explicitly defining landscape resources.

Your options include

- use number or `@dimen` or `@style` in layout xml files for `android:textSize`
- use number or `@dimen` [to define `@style` in styles.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html) over a `TextAppearance` parent style's textSize
- [define `@dimen` value in dimens.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)